# Sitecore GlassMapper and Json.NET

Tags: glass-mapper, json

I need to pass parameters in *Json* format from Sitecore item. I am getting Sitecore item using *GlassMapper*.

```
public interface ISomeType
{
  //some fields
}
public interface ISomeFolder
{
    IEnumerable<ISomeType> SubItems { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var folder = _sitecoreContext.GetItem<ISomeFolder>(dataSourceId)
var list = folder.SubItems;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list); // <= Here I get "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."
```

List type is `Glass.Mapper.Sc.LazyItemEnumerable<ISomeType>`. It contains `Castle.Proxies.ISomeTypeProxy` items, I can access to them. I can access to all their fields described in the interface. But I am getting *System.StackOverflowException* exception when trying to serialize it.

Is it possible to serialize *GlassMapper* objects to *Json* using *Newtonsoft Json.NET*?

If yes then what I am doing wrong? If no, what is the best way to convert *GlassMapper* object to *Json*?

Comment: The way I do it is I create a JSon-specific item that contains a subset of the fields of the original Glass-mapped item; that's because some fields may not be serializable.

Also you should use the actuall item, not the Glass Mapper Proxy one (which you may get if your Glass item is lazy-loaded).

Comment: I believe the `StackOverflowException` is thrown because (depending on how you have your models set up) it tries to serialize all the parents/children, which in turn serializes their parents/children, etc.

Comment: @DanSinclair I have tried to avoid parents/children serialization by handling reference loop in *ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore*. But with no luck. Result is the same.

Comment: It's not referencing a loop, it's just referencing all items in both directions from your item, which will (eventually) try to serialize every item in the entire Sitecore tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this would be to use either a custom class or a dynamic one when you serialize:

```
var folder = _sitecoreContext.GetItem<ISomeFolder>(dataSourceId)
var list = folder.SubItems;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list.Select(subitem => new 
                                                   { 
                                                       subitem.Field1,
                                                       subitem.Field2,
                                                       CustomFieldName = subitem.Field3
                                                   }));
```

Comment: Elegant solution, and quicker than the one I use! Repped.